# Download Excel file from server and save on client

Tags: javascript, excel, blob, filereader

I have a JavaScript app and an API that creates a Excel file and returns a byte array with the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=List.xlsx
```

When I go the Excel resource API URL I'm prompted to download the Excel file. If I do so, it downloads fine and opens in Excel. All is good.

Now to the problem:

What I don't want is to expose the API URL in the user's browser window, so my goal is to:

- Download the Excel file via AJAX XMLHttpRequest
- Store the contents (byte array) in a Blob
- Create a data URI with the Blob
- Open the data URI in a popup, that prompts the user to download the Excel file

What I have is this:

*It downloads the file, but when I try to open the file, Excel doesn't recognize it as a valid Excel file.*

```
// "data" is the contents from the server

var reader = new FileReader();
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    window.open(reader.result, 'Excel', 'width=20,height=10,toolbar=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Does this need to work in IE?

Comment: I solved it (see answer below), but you're right, IE doesn't support this. Can it be made available for IE?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it working. I just had to add the following to my XMLHttpRequest object:

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
```

But it doesn't work in IE, because IE cannot open data URIs. Not even IE11.

Anyway I found [a great library called FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) which handles saving files for all major browsers (including IE10+)

Comment: I used `responseType: 'blob'`. Keep in mind that `responseType` is not a HTTP header that you send with the request, but a property of the `XMLHttpRequest` object!